# Removing and adding a class on list item click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a list item with save post text and it has a class of `save-post` and when I click on it I want to change the text of this list item into unsave post and replace the class `save-post` within unsave-post class I tried to do this but the change in list item text and class happens only for one time ..

```js
$('.save-post').click(function(){
  $(this).text('Unsave Post');
  $(this).removeClass('save-post');
  $(this).addClass('unsave-post');
});    
$('.unsave-post').click(function(){
  $(this).text('Save Post');
  $(this).removeClass('unsave-post');
  $(this).addClass('save-post');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 drop">
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v post-drop"></i></a>
   <div class="drop-content">
     <ul>
       <li class="save-post">Save post</li>
     <li>Report post</li>
     <li>Hide post</li>
     <li>Unfollow User</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the html and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt?

Comment: rather than binding it to a class that you change, give it another class that doesn't change and bind it to that, otherwise delegate you event

Comment: Everyone answered with **how** to do it, nobody explained **why** the binding is no longer working after the class is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass()` method and then check the applied class and append the appropriate text

```js
$(document).on('click', '.save-post, .unsave-post', function(e) {
  var that = $(e.currentTarget);
  that.toggleClass('save-post unsave-post');
  if (that.hasClass('save-post')) {
    that.html('Save post');
  } else {
    that.html('Unsave post');    
  }  
});
```

```css
.save-post {
  color: green
}
.unsave-post {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="save-post">Save post</li>
  <li class="save-post">Save post</li>
  <li class="save-post">Save post</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanx a lot you saved my day I was not sure about how to use toggle in such cases

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.click()` is bind event to target selector but after click it class 
changed to another. You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-post', function(){
    $(this).text('Unsave Post');
    $(this).removeClass('save-post');
    $(this).addClass('unsave-post');
});    
$(document).on('click', '.unsave-post', function(){
    $(this).text('Save Post');
    $(this).removeClass('unsave-post');
    $(this).addClass('save-post');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.save-post', function(){
    $(this).text('Unsave Post');
    $(this).removeClass('save-post');
    $(this).addClass('unsave-post');
});    
$(document).on('click', '.unsave-post', function(){
    $(this).text('Save Post');
    $(this).removeClass('unsave-post');
    $(this).addClass('save-post');
});
```

```css
.save-post {color: red}
.unsave-post {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 drop">
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v post-drop"></i></a>
  <div class="drop-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="save-post">Save post</li>
      <li>Report post</li>
      <li>Hide post</li>
      <li>Unfollow User</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.click` will only attach events to elements that already exist.

You need to use a event handler which monitors for dynamically created clicked events like this `on('click',`

Then, you can use toggleClass like this

```js
$('.save-post').on('click',function(){
   if ($(this).text() == "Save post")
      $(this).text("Unsave post")
   else
      $(this).text("Save post");
   $(this).toggleClass('save-post');
   $(this).toggleClass('unsave-post');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 drop">
   <a href=""><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v post-drop"></i></a>
   <div class="drop-content">
     <ul>
         <li class="save-post">Save post</li>
         <li>Report post</li>
         <li>Hide post</li>
         <li>Unfollow User</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```